# How to use underscore .groupBy function to group an array of json objects based on multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of json objects who results I want to [groupBy()](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) based on multiple properties i.e.,

I have:

```
[
  {
     prop1:val1,
     prop2:val2,
     prop3:val3,
     prop4:val4
  }
]
```

Now if I just wanted to group by `prop1` I guess I could have done :

```
_.groupBy(givenArray, 'prop1');
```

Now what should I do if I have to group by `prop1`,`prop2` and `prop3`, i.e., `(prop1 && prop2 && prop3)`

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that target values to an `array`, and then form them to `string`, or just transform them to string form and combine:

```
_.groupBy(givenArray, function(item) {
   var keys = _.pick(item, 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3');
   // If all are string or number,
   // return keys.join('_@%@_'); // this prevent ['ab', 'a'] generate same key to ['a', 'ba'];
   return JSON.stringify(keys);
});
```

`JSON.stringify` maybe one of the many ways to create a combined key, I'm not sure what your `vals` is (string, number or else), so I'll just use stringify here.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want your final structure to be.

If you don't mind a non-flat object structure, you can do nested `_.groupBy` calls:

```
var result = _(givenArray) //begin chain
.groupBy('a')
.mapValues(function(groupedByA) {
     return _(groupedByA) //begin chain
    .groupBy('b')
    .mapValues(function (groupedByAAndB) {
        return _.groupBy(groupedByAAndB, 'c');
    })
    .value(); //end chain
})
.value(); //end chain
//Then you can do things like:
result[5][4][3]; //All items where a=5, b=4, and c=3.
```

Downside here is that there's an extra level of nesting for each property you group by, and `result[5][4]` will blow up if there aren't any results where `a=5` for example. (Though you could use a library like [koalaesce](https://github.com/ssube/koalaesce) for that)

Alternatively, if you want a flat object structure, but don't mind it being a bit ungainly to access the items, then:

```
var result = _.groupBy(givenArray, function (item) {
    return JSON.stringify(_.pick(item, 'a','b','c'));
});

//Much simpler above, but accessed like: 
result[JSON.stringify({a: 5, b:4, c:3})]
```

Much simpler and scales better to grouping by more things... but awkward to work with, since the keys are full JSON strings; but then you also don't have the `null` issue that the first option has.

You can also, just use `_.values` or some equivalent to turn the flat object structure into a single array of arrays.  Then there's obviously no "random" access to get all items with a given value of a,b, and c, but you can always loop over it.